# Can this be simplified further? (Logical equivalence)

Tags: logic

1. (~p^(p->q))-> ~q      [Premise]
2. ~(~p^(p->q)) v ~q     [Implication]
3. (p v ~(~p v q)) v ~q  [Implication and De Morgan's]
4. (p v (p ^ ~q)) v ~q   [De Morgan's]
5. (p v ~q) v (p ^ ~q)   [Associative]
6. ??

Not sure what the next step is.

Comment: Well, if you back up to 4, then absorption would apply in one of the terms there.

Comment: So I would end up with p v ~q, correct? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you'd end up with $p\lor \lnot q$