# Can logical equivalence be simplified in terms of simpler logical operators

Tags: boolean-algebra, equivalence-relations

I have been researching the net for an answer, but sadly to no avail. I know implication can be simplified into simpler operators using de Morgan's and associative laws (such as this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950598/can-this-be-simplified-further-logical-equivalence) demonstrates), but I have found no similar solution for equivalence.

The logical compound expression that I am trying to simplify is the following using only conjunction, disjunction and negation:

$$\neg(((A\rightarrow \neg B) \,\&\, C) \vee (\neg A\leftrightarrow\neg C)$$

Thank you very much taken for the explanation!

Comment: I've edited your question; in the future, you should use [mathjax]() for formatting mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're thinking too hard about this. Look back at how bi-implication is **defined** in the first place: by definition, $A\leftrightarrow B$ is equivalent to

> $(A\rightarrow B) \,\&\, (B\rightarrow A)$.

So if we know how to "unpack" $\rightarrow$, we can similarly "unpack" $\leftrightarrow$.

Of course this gets lengthy, but that's why we use abbreviations like $\leftrightarrow$ in the first place.

Comment: As a quick comment, note that "$\wedge$" is more commonly used for conjunction than "$\&$" in mathematical logic.

Comment: Oops, this totally slipped my mind. Had to ask in a rush :(. Thank you for the help though, with your tip I've managed to solve the task!